# Как реализовать BroadcastReceiver на версии андроид 4.3?

Tags: android, java

Дело в том, что на версии 2.3.3 все работает отлично, при запуске на версии 4.3 никаких "эмоций" Привожу установки проекта. Пожалуйста, скажите в чем дело?

```
 Minimum Required SDK - 2.2
 Target SDK - 2.3.3
 Compile With - 4.3
```

Класс ресивера

```
package com.samples.telephony.receiversms;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_REC_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SmsReceiver.SMS_REC_ACTION)){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                sb.append("\nAdres: " + smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress());
                sb.append("\nAdres: " + smsMessage.getMessageBody());
                }
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sms Resiver mesage" + sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}}
```

и манифест

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.samples.telephony.receiversms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application></manifest>
```

*Обновление*

Я только начинаю и поэтому могу не понять. Я создал класс

```
publicclassMainextendsActivity{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    @Override
    protectedvoidonCreate(BundlesavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Receiver name: " + info.activityInfo.name+ "; priority= " + info.priority);}}}
```

Мне его в манифесте надо указывать? В логе нет Receiver name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
  <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true"
            >
        <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**P.S.** Ресивер пишется не Resiver, а Receiver

**Update**

Тогда так (код для Kitkat):

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >
        <intent-filter
            <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
            android:priority="2147483647"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Update 2**

@FFFNikolay Голощапов это конечно сила - я сражен.

1. Вы пишете о каком-то диалоге (в ваших исходниках его нет)
2. Проверить работает ресивер или нет надо проверять не наличием/отсутствием диалога, а логгированием.
3. Так про между прочим. Запускать так просто из ресивера компоненты приложения невозможно (диалоги, активити). "Незапуск" ресивера очевидно связан с этим - вы пытаетесь судить о работе ресивера запуском диалога, а диалог просто так из ресивера запустить [невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot).
4. Постарайтесь не быть такими категоричными в своих суждениях. И выучите что такое логгирование, в частности, что такое LogCat, иначе рискуете заработать в форуме не очень лестную репутацию :)

Comment: @FFFNikolay это все недокументировано, поэтому все так сложно. Смотрите апдейт. И, кстати, что за аппарат то?

Comment: @FFFNikolay см. апдейт #2 в ответе

Comment: @FFFNikolay а еще ключ от квартиры где деньги лежат? Вставьте лог в onReceive() - и увидите, что все работает. Toast из ресивера будет работать если только есть живой `Activity`, а у вас этого походу нет - поэтому вы не видите `Toast` - еще один такой идиотский вопрос начну минусовать!

Comment: @FFFNikolay, почему не работает на 4.3 а работает на 2.3.3? Во первых, наверное потому что внутренние процессы у этих систем кардинально различаются. Проверьте работу логгированием как советуют. ПОтому что проблема скорее всего в том что в 2.3.3 код ресивера идёт в UI потоке и тоаст отрабатывает, а в 4.3 не в UI и у Вас оно тупо падает.

Answer (score 1):

А логировать запуска ресивера пробовали? Он запускается, но не срабатывает код внутри или он не запускается вовсе? Кстати натыкались на эту ссылку? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030777. Если нет, попробуйте, вдруг поможет.

*Обновление*

По ссылке так же решается проблема неработающего ресивера. В том случае сработал вариант перекрытия - у другого приложения приоритет ресивера оказался выше и он отключал остальные ресиверы. Попробуйте запустить вот этот код в активити, в onCreate своего приложения и напишите, что вывелось в LogCat:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Receiver name: " + info.activityInfo.name + "; priority= " + info.priority);
}
```